# How can I interpret the Interaction term of a quantile regression ? where interaction made between two continous variable

Tags: quantile-regression

I fit a quantile regression model . Where I take a interaction term height and weight . i want to see the effect of height and weight on BMI. I get the estimates -0.51 at the 5th quantile. How can I interpret this? Advance Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreting an interaction in a quantile regression is very similar to interpreting one in a "regular" regression, except that you are modeling a quantile rather than the mean.  It measures how the relationship between the DV and one IV changes as the other IV changes.  Yours says that the relationship between 5th percentile BMI and height is different at different weights (and, similarly, the relationship with weight is different at different heights).

However, your example is very strange.  BMI is *defined* as the ratio of weight to height squared.  There's not much sense in doing a regression on this.